# Report not returning data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using an SP in dataset and that is returning rows when I pass parameters. But, even when I pass same set of parameter to view report, it doesn't retun any rows in the report. Please let me know what could be the issue.

Comment: Please provide code to understand it better.what i assume is it could be the issue with datatype and you may have to convert it before passing.

Comment: Please update your question with the steps you have tried so far. You can start by checking the database your report is connecting to, check for error messages in SSRS, check for filters in your dataset, groups, and table.